Convert a dataframe where each row has categorical data into a new dataframe with each category represented as a separate column
The following dataframe has one row per each patient (the rowids correspond to the patients), and one single column.
df <- data.frame(
  mutations = c('A497T', NA, 'C320T', 'A497T', NA, 'G621C', 'G621C')
)

This column tells whether the patient (row), has a given mutation, or not (NA).
I want to create a new dataframe where every unique mutation corresponds to a column, so for example, the first column will be "A497T", and every patient that presents this mutation will have a "Yes" value.
Same for the rest of the columns.
Original dataframe
mutations
<chr>
A497T               
NA              
C320T               
A497T               
NA              
G621C               
G621C

Desired output
A497T  | C320T  |  G621C
<chr>  | <chr>  |  <chr>
Yes    |NA      |NA
NA     |NA      |NA
NA     |Yes     |NA
Yes    |NA      |NA
NA     |NA      |NA
NA     |NA      |Yes
NA     |NA      |Yes


You can use table:
table(rownames(df), df$mutations)
    A497T C320T G621C
  1     1     0     0
  2     0     0     0
  3     0     1     0
  4     1     0     0
  5     0     0     0
  6     0     0     1
  7     0     0     1


very elegant +1

I think you are looking for pivot_wider:
library(tidyverse)

df_tst <- data.frame(mutations= c("A497T",NA,"C320T", "A497T", NA, "G621C", "G621C"))                     

# Add an ID column to ensure each row can be uniquely identified
df_tst <- df_tst %>% mutate(id = row_number())

# Pivot 
df_pivoted <- df_tst %>%
  mutate(presence = "yes") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = mutations, values_from = presence, values_fill = list(presence = NA)) %>%
  select(-id) 

df_pivoted

# A tibble: 7 × 4
  A497T `NA`  C320T G621C
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 yes   NA    NA    NA   
2 NA    yes   NA    NA   
3 NA    NA    yes   NA   
4 yes   NA    NA    NA   
5 NA    yes   NA    NA   
6 NA    NA    NA    yes  
7 NA    NA    NA    yes 

